# OpenShift node not connecting to image registry

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-origin, docker-registry

I configured openshift and everything is working properly on host where docker-register is started. When i added new node and i try to deploy containers on it i have such error in logs:

```
E0519 10:51:38.574152    2135 pod_workers.go:138] Error syncing pod 083b958e-1dc0-11e6-8ca2-525400c36a07, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "testapp4" with ImagePullBackOff: "Back-off pulling image \"172.30.236.174:5000/test/testapp4@sha256:64c3dc4cb983986a1dd5a7979f03f449b089f4baaf979b67363a92aac43e49cd\""

E0519 11:00:09.099712    2098 pod_workers.go:138] Error syncing pod 5d3c48a1-1dd2-11e6-a164-525400c36a07, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "testapp4" with ErrImagePull: "API error (500): Get http://172.30.236.174:5000/v2/: dial tcp 172.30.236.174:5000: getsockopt: no route to host\n"
```

I'm guessing problem is with it that new node not "see" docker-registry address 172.30.236.174 which is deployed on other node. Should i do something more with new node (i just started openshift with node config)?

Answer (score 2):

`172.30.0.0/16` is used by OpenShift to allocate virtual IP addresses for Kubernetes Services. The docker registry is made available via a Service, and it has apparently bound `172.30.236.174` in your cluster. Service addresses are not normally routable -- instead, `kube-proxy` intercepts outbound traffic addressed to that IP address, and redirects it (see [Virtual IPs and service proxies](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies)).

The error message "no route to host", associated with the virtual IP address, indicates that the `kube-proxy` is not working on the new node. You should be able to find the process running, and you should be able to find its rules in the `iptables -L` output.

Comment: How kubernetes/openshift is downloading images, in that case, if registry is working in internal environment? How images are downloaded to nodes as docker containers are on top of it?